# UWP APP Use Xbox controller instead of mouse

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a C# app with a mediaPlayerElement and a WebView in the WebView Javascript 
i set

```
window.navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = 'keyboard';
```

and in the c# constructor i set

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never;
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }
```

However once i launch the media player a cursor is displayed and when the mediaplayer is closed the cursor remains and i can no longer navigate the app using the xbox controller. Xaml below

```
    <Page
        x:Class="App19.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:App19"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <MediaPlayerElement
            x:Name="media"
            KeyUp="Media_KeyUp"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Width="1300" 
            AutoPlay="True"
            RequiresPointer="Never"
            reTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
        <WebView 
            x:Name="MyWebView" DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent" 
          NavigationStarting ="webView_NavigationStarting" ScriptNotify = 
       "MyWebView_ScriptNotify" />  
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

i want to disable the mouse cursor throughout the app. Any know how i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn off mouse mode, add the following to the constructor for your app:

```
public App() 
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.RequiresPointerMode = 
    Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

Taken from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode)

Comment: Error CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object

Comment: The code compiles, I've tested it myself. Are you adding it in the correct place? It should be added to App.xaml.cs

Comment: oops I was. Works great Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!